# Is Ubuntu doing GUI research?

Tags: unity, canonical, design, usability

Is there any serious graphical user interface research for Ubuntu? I mean, are there any improvements planned by Ubuntu in order to improve it's default user interface? Just for example I don't understand why are there two upper bars on every window, menu and controls like close, minimize, maximize, when the title is not very useful.

Comment: Look around the [Ubuntu | Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) website.

Comment: Now it is implemented by default.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Canonical design team](http://design.canonical.com) regularly conducts GUI researches and usability tests on different types of people.

Check out [their blog](http://design.canonical.com) for more on what they're up to!

Comment: Especially http://design.canonical.com/category/research/ and http://design.canonical.com/the-research/

Comment: After a while some stuff is implemented. Thanks Ubuntu for fonts.

Answer (score 7):

See the work of the Ayatana project, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana

Every person may have a personal view on how the UI should look like. It is important to be receptive to change and open-minded.